# Difference between integers and rational numbers by using the form $a/b$.

Tags: real-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $a$ and $b$ two positive integers such that $b≠0$.

How one can makes a difference between **integers** and **rational numbers** by using the form $q=a/b$, i.e., cases of the form:

$q$ is an integer if and only if conditions on $a$ and $b$.

$q$ is a rational number and not an integer if and only if conditions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $q=a/b$ is an integer iff $b|a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every integer $n\in\Bbb Z$ is also a rational number, since one way of writing it as a fraction is $\frac{n}{1}$.

If you want do distinguish between rational numbers that are and aren't integers you could have,

$$q=\frac{a}{b}\text{ is an integer }\iff b\mid a$$